# Possible to run command like "pod install" or "Pod::Command::Install.run" while developing a pre-hook cocoapods plugin?

Tags: ios, plugins, flutter, cocoapods, podfile

I am creating a cocoapods plugin to seamlessly integrate flutter into an existing iOS project without polluting the main project.

The [cocoapods plugin](https://github.com/upgrad/cocoapods-integrate-flutter) will be applied to the main project Podfile and will run [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/templates/module/ios/library/Flutter.tmpl/podhelper.rb) ruby file from the flutter repository. I am almost done with the plugin development, in fact, this will run with no problems if the flutter project does not contain any plugins.

But there is a [code](https://github.com/upgrad/cocoapods-integrate-flutter/blob/b0192c19997b7d084cf22485ba09cc657b633998/lib/cocoapods-integrate-flutter/flutter_pre_install_script.rb#L35) that runs when the flutter project contains plugins. This script creates a symlink hidden directory inside the flutter application path and adds plugins' directories in it. Then it calls `pod install` with that path to install plugins as `pod` dependencies in the main project. I want to do all of this inside the plugin.

Currently running this plugin gives me following error:
`NoMethodError - undefined method pod for <CocoapodsIntegrateFlutter::IntegrateFlutter:0x00007fa5b1f7c110>` which is understandable since `pod` essentially is an executable.

Is it possible to call `pod install` or `Pod::Command::Install.run` or something like this to add new dependencies from the plugin to the Podfile?

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Rome might be helpful

Comment: thanks for the link @PaulBeusterien but this will force me to write pre compile and post compile script in the main project's Podfile and I do not want to pollute that file or any other part of the main project.